# Simple code for blinking led using Java eclipse kura GPIO?

Tags: java, eclipse, raspberry-pi, iot, kura

I'm currently working on IoT using Kura.
A simple guide with example of using eclipse kura along with raspberry pi will also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend first reviewing the [Eclipse Kura documentation](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/). There are many examples in there, including an [example for driving an LED](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/devices/1-gpio-driver.html).

--Dave

Comment: Thanks We were successful on implementing simple kura pgm, but the documentation is not for beginners (couldn't find any other though), few steps are missing and some are repeating making it confusing to make 1st kura program.